# Animation of Circle angle rotation using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, rotation, geometry, angle

I have a circle and  partition this circle into 3 sector(120 angle each).Now I want to increase angle  50 degree to one part and decrease 50 degree to another part and keep constant third part (like 170 degree for first part,70 degree for second and 120 degree third).I want to make a animation for the whole process using MATLAB.

How can I get this? If anyone have any source code for this process using MATLAB, it helps me much.

I just draw a circle and divide it three equal sectors and polt some points into the circle.Here, i attached the following code:

```
x0=2;   
y0=1;    
r=1;    
teta=-pi:0.01:pi;    
x=r*cos(teta)+x0    
y=r*sin(teta)+y0    
plot(x,y)    
hold on    
scatter(x0,y0,'or')    
axis square 

%----------------------------------------
% divide your circle to n sectors

n=3    
tet=linspace(-pi,pi,n+1)    
xi=r*cos(tet)+x0    
yi=r*sin(tet)+y0    
for k=1:numel(xi)    
    plot([x0 xi(k)],[y0 yi(k)])    
    hold on    
    p1=[1.5,0.4];   
    p2=[2,0.8];    
    p3=[2.5,0.2];    
    p4=[2.5,1];   
    p5=[1.5,1.6];    
    p6=[1.5,0.8];    
    p7=[2,1.2];    
    p8=[2,1.4];    
    p9=[1.6,0.7];    
    p10=[2.5,0.6];    
    p11=[2.7,0.5];    
    p12=[2,0.9];
    p=[p1;p2;p3;p4;p5;p6;p7;p8;p9;p10;p11;p12]';     
    plot(p(1,:),p(2,:),'go')    
end
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Dieter, i attached my simple code in question.

Comment: Im not saying to share the whole code, but I think a more complete piece of code would let more people able to help you;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will produce exactly what you want. I simplified some of your code and added comments to the sections. All the parameters can be set at the top. The script will create a movie file `circle_anim.mp4` that can be viewed outside Matlab.

```
% set options
x0 = 2;     % origin x-coordinate
y0 = 1;     % origin y-coordinate
r  = 1;     % radius of circle
n  = 3;     % number of pieces
m  = 50;    % movement of separator in radians (+ACW / -CW)
ts = 3;     % target separator (1...n)
fs = 30;    % frame rate in fps
T  = 2;     % duration in seconds
s  = T*fs;  % movement step count

% predefined points -> [x1,x2,xn;y1,y2,yn]
p = [ 1.5, 2.0, 2.50, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0, 1.6, 2.5, 2.7, 2.0;
      0.4, 0.8, 0.20, 1.0, 1.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.9];

% calculate circle
theta = -pi:0.01:pi;    
cirx = r*cos(theta) + x0;    
ciry = r*sin(theta) + y0;

% initial plot
figure; hold on;
axis square;
plot(x0,y0,'or');           % origin
plot(cirx,ciry);            % circle
plot(p(1,:),p(2,:),'go');   % predefined points

% calculate and plot separations
ciro = linspace(-pi,pi,n+1);
for k = 1:(numel(ciro)-1)
    ph(k) = plot([x0,x0+r*cos(ciro(k))],[y0,y0+r*sin(ciro(k))]); %#ok<SAGROW>
end

% vary target separator and create frames
clearvars myFrames;
movo = linspace(ciro(ts),ciro(ts)+(m/180*pi),s);
for k = 1:numel(movo)
    set(ph(ts), 'XData', [x0,x0+r*cos(movo(k))]);
    set(ph(ts), 'YData', [y0,y0+r*sin(movo(k))]);
    myFrames(k) = getframe;  %#ok<SAGROW>
end

% write frames to video
myMovie = VideoWriter('circle_anim.mp4','MPEG-4');
myMovie.FrameRate = fs;
open(myMovie);
for k = 1:length(myFrames)
    writeVideo(myMovie,myFrames(k));
end
close(myMovie);
```

Comment: I marked it.I have a another question. Suppose,if i want to add some label in figure like initial angle 120 for each (show this label beside each part of circle), when rotate label change in 70,170,120. Is it possible to visualize and add in code. If possible, how can i get this. Please,if you have any idea,share with me...